# error linking to LibPng library

Tags: linker, symlink, undefined-reference, libpng

I am having trouble linking to the libpng library.
The build seems unable to define references to Libpng calls.
I think the problem is in my Libpng install.

I am runing in the Mingw environment on a Win7 laptop
My build environment is as follows:

```
My path starts with C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\git\cmd;C:\Program Files 


C:\Users\Bob\Home\png23d>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.3.0

I have built and installed libpng-1.6.28 which creates the following:
C:\MinGW\bin>
    libpng-config
    libpng16-config
    libpng16.dll

C:\MinGW\include\libpng
    png.h
    pngconf.h
    pnglibconf.h

C:\MinGW\include\libpng16
    png.h
    pngconf.h
    pnglibconf.h

C:\MinGW\lib\pkgconfig

C:\MinGW\lib>
    libpng.a
    libpng.dll.a
    libpng16.a
    libpng16.dll.a

a symbolic link `libpng' to `libpng16'
a symbolic link `libpng.pc' to `libpng16.pc'
a symbolic link `libpng.a' to `libpng16.a'
a symbolic link `libpng-config' to `libpng16-config
```

when I try to build a program "png23d" I get the following

```
C:\Users\Bob\Home\png23d>make
g++ -DUSE_LIBPNG -lpng  png23d.o option.o bitmap.o mesh.o mesh_gen.o mesh_index.o mesh_simplify.o out_pgm.o out_rscad.o out_pscad.o out_stl.o   -o png23d

bitmap.o:bitmap.c:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `png_sig_cmp'
bitmap.o:bitmap.c:(.text+0x142): undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
     .
     .
     .
bitmap.o:bitmap.c:(.text+0x418): undefined reference to `png_read_end'
bitmap.o:bitmap.c:(.text+0x466): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'png23d' failed
make: *** [png23d] Error 1
```

I am almost sure its the -lpng that is not working.... I am just don't know how to fix it.
I am guessing that it is a symbolic link problem and I know I did not create one during the libpng build.
If I am right what do I need to link it to.

I tried changing -lpng to -llpng16. It made no difference.

Thanks from the command prompt that work fine.
just have to figure out how to change the make file.

```
#!/usr/bin/make
#
# png23d is a program to convert png images into 3d files
#
# Copyright 2011 Vincent Sanders <vince@kyllikki.org>
#
# Released under the MIT License, 
#   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

CC = g++

VERSION=100

PREFIX = 

WARNFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wundef -Wpointer-arith \
        -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes \
        -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls \
        -Wnested-externs
ifneq ($(GCCVER),2)
  WARNFLAGS += -Wno-unused-parameter 
endif

OPTFLAGS=-O2
#OPTFLAGS=-O0

CFLAGS+=$(WARNFLAGS) -MMD -DVERSION=$(VERSION) $(OPTFLAGS) -g

LDFLAGS+= -DUSE_LIBPNG -lpng

PNG23D_OBJ=png23d.o option.o bitmap.o mesh.o mesh_gen.o mesh_index.o mesh_simplify.o out_pgm.o out_rscad.o out_pscad.o out_stl.o

.PHONY : all clean

all:png23d

png23d:$(PNG23D_OBJ)

-include $(PNG23D_OBJ:.o=.d)

-include test/Makefile.sub

clean: testclean
    ${RM} png23d $(PNG23D_OBJ) *.d *~ png23d.png

install:png23d
    install -D png23d $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin

install-man:png23d.1
    install -D png23d.1 $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/share/man/man1

# logo creation
png23d.png:png23d.pov
    povray +L/usr/share/povray/include/ -D +Q11 +O$@ +UV +UL +A0.2 +FP8 +W400 +H300 $<
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `-lpng` to after the object files.

Comment: Thanks from the command prompt that work fine.
Just have to figure out how to change the makefile.
makefile added to main question

Comment: @RobertWorkman Try putting `-lpng` to `LDLIBS` instead (see [make docs](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html) for detailed info about implicit makefile rules).